# New AKS cluster unreachable via network (including dashboard)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

Yesterday I spun up an Azure Kubernetes Service cluster running a few simple apps. Three of them have exposed public IPs that were reachable yesterday.

As of this morning I can't get the dashboard tunnel to work or the `LoadBalancer` IPs themselves.

I was asked by the Azure twitter account to solicit help here.

**I don't know how to troubleshoot this apparent network issue - only `az` seems to be able to touch my cluster.**

### dashboard error log

`❯❯❯ make dashboard                                                                                        ~/c/azure-k8s (master)
az aks browse --resource-group=akc-rg-cf --name=akc-237
Merged "akc-237" as current context in /var/folders/9r/wx8xx8ls43l8w8b14f6fns8w0000gn/T/tmppst_atlw
Proxy running on http://127.0.0.1:8001/
Press CTRL+C to close the tunnel...
error: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.240.0.4:10250: getsockopt: connection timed out`

### service+pod listing

`❯❯❯ kubectl get services,pods                                                                             ~/c/azure-k8s (master)
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
azure-vote-back    ClusterIP      10.0.125.49    <none>           6379/TCP       16h
azure-vote-front   LoadBalancer   10.0.185.4     40.71.248.106    80:31211/TCP   16h
hubot              LoadBalancer   10.0.20.218    40.121.215.233   80:31445/TCP   26m
kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>           443/TCP        19h
mti411-web         LoadBalancer   10.0.162.209   52.168.123.30    80:30874/TCP   26m`

`NAME                                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
azure-vote-back-7556ff9578-sjjn5    1/1       Running   0          2h
azure-vote-front-5b8878fdcd-9lpzx   1/1       Running   0          16h
hubot-74f659b6b8-wctdz              1/1       Running   0          9s
mti411-web-6cc87d46c-g255d          1/1       Running   0          26m
mti411-web-6cc87d46c-lhjzp          1/1       Running   0          26m`

### http failures

`❯❯❯ curl --connect-timeout 2 -I http://40.121.215.233                                                     ~/c/azure-k8s (master)
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 2005 milliseconds
❯❯❯ curl --connect-timeout 2 -I http://52.168.123.30                                                      ~/c/azure-k8s (master)
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 2001 milliseconds`

Comment: We have had similar problems that were solved by rebooting the nodes from the Azure portal. I don't know if it helps and it hides the root cause, but it may get your cluster back up.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I'm not sure what to think about that but it did help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting **getsockopt: connection timed out** while trying to access to your AKS Dashboard, I think deleting tunnelfront pod will help as once you delete the tunnelfront pod, this will trigger creation of new tunnelfront by Master. Its something I have tried and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@daniel Did rebooting the agent VM's solve your issue or are you still seeing issues?

Comment: The issue hasn't come back but I am a bit nervous about it - I need my k8s cluster to have externally visible IPs if I'm going to be able to use it for client work!